# when i try to execute this line through nodejs, its throwing document not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i try to execute this line through **nodeJS**, its **throwing document not defined??** is there any wrong with this, whether i need to define **document** in java script code.**Document** showing here refers what? Need suggestions, valuable comments are welcome

```
var list = document.createElement("ul"); 
list.setAttribute("id","id");
```

> ReferenceError: document is not defined..

Comment: you need to define document in javascript in front-end. document refer to HTML page/document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is a Javascript runtime environment, which is separate from running Javascript in the browser.

In the browser there is a global object called `document` that controls the DOM, whereas in NodeJS there is no browser, thus no `document` object. So calling `document.createElement()` throws an error because `document` doesn't exist.